# What large dog breeds can handle a day long hike?

Tags: breeds, large-dogs

Large dogs are not typically high energy dogs. "Don't hike with your mastiff farther than you can carry him" :-)

I love large dogs, and I love hiking.

Are there any large breeds that could accompany me on a day long hike like my German Shepherd or my Border Collie can?

Comment: How large do you consider a "large dog breed" to be? In my mind both German Shepherd and Border Collie are already in the medium-large category. How much larger do you want to go? And maybe more important: When considering adding a new dog to your family, you should chose based on which personality best fits your life style, not on the appearance of a breed.

Comment: @elmy Border collie is considered a medium sizer dog and German Shepherd medium,-large. So something bigger than a German Shepherd. Fluffiness also matters, fluffy dogs look bigger :-)

Comment: For me the reason of the phrase "not further than you can carry the dog" comes from the possibility of injuries. You should always be able to carry your dog to the next street, where a car can collect it...

Comment: What is a long day hike to you? How far do you go, and how often? Do you make sure the dogs stay active on off days, or do they mostly rest? What climates do you hike in, and at what elevations? Many breeds larger than a German Shepard are more prone to joint issues, overheating, and heart conditions. Fluffy dogs especially will get hot, faster.

Comment: no matter what dog you have you need to exercise and gradualy build speed and distance if you want to do long hikes with him/her.